# Notification close

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications

I have an Ongoing notification on my radio app and I already managed to start my main activity from the notification but now I'm trying to add a button to the notification to stop the streaming service.

This is my notifaction method inside the service:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void createNotification() {
        int myIconId = R.drawable.ic_pause;
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(context, RadiophonyService.class);
        Notification notification;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("list", list);
        PendingIntent stopIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, mIntent, 0) ;
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class)
                        .putExtras(bundle), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
            notification = new Notification();
            notification.tickerText = station.getRadioName();
            notification.icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;


        } else {
            notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(station.getRadioName())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                            `enter code here`        context.getResources(),
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                    .addAction(myIconId, "STOP", stopIntent)
                    .setOngoing(true).setContentIntent(pi).build();


        }

        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

This is my OnStartCommand:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent.getAction()!=null && intent.getAction().equals("STOP")){
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
    else {
        task = new ProgressTask();
        task.execute();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

[screenshot](http://canli-radyodinle.com/112.PNG)

How can I stop the flow of services ??

Comment: I'm trying to add a button to stop the notification service flow.
how can I do it.

Comment: pls check android notifications->add action , need to explore a step and then come back here if you face an error or exception ..that would be good, you will find a solution easily..this is like requirement specification :)

Comment: See her :  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: Or use custom Notification, see here for sample : http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/02/20/how-to-create-a-custom-notification-on-android/

Comment: please help me . I still have not been resolved